# WSGI Flask - Deploy on Apache2

Tags: python, ubuntu, flask, apache2, wsgi

I have changed my goal here so here is a new question, and i hope somebody can help me with this.
I have a domene, let us call it blabla.com - and i want my flask-app to be available in blabla.com/login  i use apache2 with cloudflare and SSL.

I have followed this guide: https://codeshack.io/login-system-python-flask-mysql/ - and my main.py is like this:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, session
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
import MySQLdb.cursors
import re

app = Flask(__name__)
```

And i have done export FLASK_APP=main.py - i dont understand how to do this with WSGI because it want work. Should the app be inside /var/www/blablabla/login or another place?

Comment: You have many different questions. I would recommend having more concrete and concise questions. https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/ https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
from flask import project as application
```

The module flask has no such thing called project.

I assume that you have created a module called flask, but this is a mistake because you are cluttering the namespace and having a collision with the actual flask library. Try changing the name.

Comment: Thank you so much! I wil try that now.

Comment: Change it to what?

Comment: To any name. Let's say you just developed Twitter, then name it twitter_backend or twitter or twitter_api